# Program to see the bytes from a file internally

Tags: text, editor, byte

Do you know if exist one program or method to see (secuences of)bytes from a text,html file?
Not to see characters, rather see the complete sequence of bytes.

recommendations?

Comment: [`vim`](http://www.vim.org/) works for me :)

Comment: why the php/html/c tags?

Comment: Cuz i didnt know where can i find it, fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, it is called hex editor... Hundreds of those exist out there.

Here are some: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

Answer (score 1):

A common hex editor allows you to view any file's byte sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the existing bytes (without changing them) you can use a hex-dump program, which is much smaller and simpler than a hex editor. For example, here's one I wrote several years ago:

```
/* public domain by Jerry Coffin
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned long offset = 0;
    FILE *input;
    int bytes, i, j;
    unsigned char buffer[16];
    char outbuffer[60];

    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: dump filename [filename...]");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (j=1;j<argc; ++j) {

        if ( NULL ==(input=fopen(argv[j], "rb")))
            continue;

        printf("\n%s:\n", argv[j]);

        while (0 < (bytes=fread(buffer, 1, 16, input))) {
            sprintf(outbuffer, "%8.8lx: ", offset+=16);
            for (i=0;i<bytes;i++) {
                sprintf(outbuffer+10+3*i, "%2.2X ",buffer[i]);
                if (!isprint(buffer[i]))
                    buffer[i] = '.';
            }
            printf("%-60s %*.*s\n", outbuffer, bytes, bytes, buffer);
        }
        fclose(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With an editor i have to change the bytes?(i dont get that point), Useful answer but im searching like an editor from the another answers, ill keep it , thank you very much. ill test all the answers and the useful for me will be the answered.

Comment: @nEAnnam: An editor will let you change bytes, but (of course) doesn't force you to. This doesn't support changing at all, just displaying.